# getting a .netcore project to run with old code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to take an non core project and transfer it to .net core. It's my first time using it.

I have a file that uses the regular expressions class, so my file looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

but I'm getting an error

> "Error    CS0234  The type or namespace name 'RegularExpressions' does not
>   exist in the namespace 'System.Text' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)   FantasySports.Server.NET Platform 5.4"

my `project.json` file looks like this

```
  "frameworks": {
"net451": { },
"net452": { },
"net46": { },
"dotnet5.4": {
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
    "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
    "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
    "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
    "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client": "5.2.2-rc",
    "System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml": "4.1.0-beta-23516",
    "System.Text.RegularExpressions": "4.1.0"
  }
}
```

}

I tried adding the `System.Text.RegularExpressions` package from `NuGet` but I still get the same error. I've also tried changing the framework for this file from 4.5.1 to 4.5 but still not working. Not really sure what I'm supposed to be doing.

Comment: Did my answer help you ?

Answer (score 0):

I have this configurations:

```
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "type": "platform"
},



  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
```

Regular expression is working properly in controller. You should put `dotnet5.6` and `portable-net45+win8`(or win7) in imports array.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    public IActionResult About()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";

        Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d+");
        Match match = regex.Match("Dot 55 Perls");

        return View();
    }
```